# Sum of a calculated textbox in ssrs reporting in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I want to calculate the sum of a calculated textbox i.e 
Table1 has two columns colA bind with database [socre] and 
                ColB has an expression
              [exp]  i.e [score]/sum[score]*100

what i want is 
TOTAL of colB               sum[colB]

Please suggest me any suggestion.

Comment: Just do the normal `SUM` expression for the textbox where you want to calculate the sum of colB. The calculated fields evaluated at the time of the data rendering.

Comment: could you please tell me what will be the expression for the textbox.

Comment: What is your caculation expression for that column ?

Comment: as i mentioned into the question my requirement is to calculate
Total=SUM[soce/sum[score]*100]